# Custom sequence of reference Id on the basis of DateTime in Sql Query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

Is it possible to write an sql query that returns
**18315-0921**

The result is time based where

**18** means 2018
**315** means day of the year
**0921** means present time.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: added @GordonLinoff

Comment: Do you need to handle dates before the year 2000?  If so, what should the YY component of your date look like?

Comment: I'm guessing `18318`  should be `18315`, and `0921` means `09:21:00` - so hours and minutes. Right?

Comment: No, I just need a simple query no matter where from the date starts. I want only a concatenated string value of above mentioned fields.

Comment: right @ZoharPeled

Comment: What have you tried? Where did it fail? SO Is not a code-writing service....

Comment: I'm a newbie @ZoharPeled. I've tried stuff like this **select Right(YEAR(CreatedOnUtc),2) from [Order]**.

Comment: @AwaisZafar you are asking how to format the current DateTime, not generate a sequence. Have you tried `FORMAT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Rob's suggesion in the comments you can do this via:  [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=17889f8015c5da92919ee4b3dde6ca58)

```sql
declare @myDateTime DateTime = getutcdate()

select format(@myDateTime, 'yy')
+ format(DatePart(dy, @myDateTime), '000')
+ format(@myDateTime, '-HHmm')
```

However, the `ddd` part isn't available this way, since `ddd` would convert to the weekday name: i.e per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/custom-date-and-time-formats-for-the-format-function).  That said, you can use this to simplify the above:  [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=466ac36da587f729960e689d6f868f14)

---

## Original solution:

Here's a solution: [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5baae9609ae3bee9c3d000b8b4c08b99)

```sql
declare @myDateTime DateTime = getutcdate()

--to get the component parts

select DatePart(YEAR, @myDateTime) - 2000 YY
, DateDiff(Day, DateFromParts(DatePart(YEAR, @myDateTime),1,1), @myDateTime) DDD
, DatePart(Hour, @myDateTime)  HH
, DatePart(Minute, @myDateTime) MM

--to format as a single string

select right('0' + cast(DatePart(YEAR, @myDateTime) - 2000 as varchar(10)), 2)
+ right('00' + cast(DateDiff(Day, DateFromParts(DatePart(YEAR, @myDateTime),1,1), @myDateTime) as varchar(10)), 3)
+ '-'
+ right('0' + cast(DatePart(Hour, @myDateTime) as varchar(10)), 2)  
+ right('0' + cast(DatePart(Minute, @myDateTime) as varchar(10)), 2)
```

- `DatePart(YEAR, @myDateTime) - 2000` gives us a 2 digit year by getting the full year (e.g. `2018` as a number, then pulling back just those digits we're interested in by subtracting `2000`)
- `DateDiff(Day, DateFromParts(DatePart(YEAR, @myDateTime),1,1), @myDateTime)` gives us the number of days since the 1st Jan in the date's year (given by `DateFromParts(DatePart(YEAR, @myDateTime),1,1))` up to the given date (so 1st Jan would be `0`; if you wanted 1st Jan to be 1, just add 1 to this result).
- The hour and the minute value are just given by pulling back those date parts.
- When we create the string we cast these numeric results to strings (varchar) and concatenate them.
- The `right('0' + /*...*/)` part allows us to right pad the digits with leading zeros, so if the time's `09:05` we get `0905` instead of `95`.

You can get almost what you're after by using the native `format` command; e.g.

```sql
select format(@myDateTime, 'yy-HHmm')
```

However, the `ddd` part isn't available this way, since `ddd` would convert to the weekday name: i.e per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/custom-date-and-time-formats-for-the-format-function).  That said, you can use this to simplify the above:  [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=466ac36da587f729960e689d6f868f14)

```
select format(@myDateTime, 'yy') 
+ right('00' + cast(DateDiff(Day, DateFromParts(DatePart(YEAR, @myDateTime),1,1), @myDateTime) as varchar(10)), 3)
+ format(@myDateTime, '-HHmm')
```

Comment: Thank you @John :)

Comment: No worries; FYI: simplified version available; see update.

Comment: @JohnLBevan, perhaps I've missed a nuance when skimming the question and your answer, but would not `DATEPART(dy, @myDateTime)` satisfy the *ddd* component?

Comment: Good shout @Rob; I wasn't familiar with `dy` (don't normally need to play with dates in SQl beyond storing or querying)... Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @TDATE as datetime2 = getdate();

select    Right('0' + CAST(YEAR(@TDATE) % 100 as varchar(2)) , 2) 
       +  RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(y,@TDATE) as varchar(3)) , 3)
       +  '-'
       + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(5),@TDATE, 114), ':', '');
```

so I'm getting the Year number in 2 digits by taking the modulus 100 of the year , e.g. 2014 % 100 is 14

then I'm changing that to a string, with a leading '0' if needed

To get the day number of the year, I'm using DatePart with 'y' to indicate 'day of year number' and that is padded with up to 2 digits if needed.

To get the time I'm converting to hh:mi:ss:mmm, but only keeping the first 5 chars, then I'm replacing the ':' with nothing

Comment: you are welcome - the best method to follow in these cases is try and work out how to do each bit, then join it together